# Any way to bypass form validation on p:commandButton without using o:ignoreValidationFailed or immediate=true

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, omnifaces

I create page forms with a parameter that tells them where to return when done.  The backing bean is `@ReqeuestScoped` and includes this:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="return" value="#{createGroup.paramReturn}" />
</f:metadata>
```

The form has fields with validators, so the cancel button has to skip validation. So, the cancel button looks like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Cancel"
                 action="#{createGroup.doCancel}"
                 immediate="true"
                 />
```

The purpose of the `doCancel()` method is to go into Flash scope and return the value set with `setParamReturn` method.

The problem is with the `immediate="true"` attribute is that the Flash storage that has the `paramReturn` variable in it is no longer available. If someone could tell me how to fix that this would be my preferred solution.

Of course without the `immediate="true"` attribute the action is never invoked because the form cannot pass validation. Another solution would be to cause validation to be ignored some other way.

I have looked at the OmniFaces `<o:ignoreValidationFailed>` tag and it seems to do what I want, but I don't want to import a whole library for just this tag. However, that is what I will do if there is no other simple way to fix this.

Comment: One way would be to use `process="@this"`. But the flash behavior on `immediate="true"` is strange. I may want to look closer at this. The `<o:ignoreValidationFailed>` has a somewhat different purpose: execute the update model values phase anyway regardless of the validation outcome.

Comment: Which jsf implementation are you using? If Mojarra, you should upgrade at the most recent, previous ones seemed to be buggy for flash.

Comment: @BalusC I tried process="@this" but I couldn't seem to get it to work -- my backing bean method was never called.  For now I have worked around the problem by storing the return in the session bean.

Comment: @XtremeBiker I am using Mojarra 2.1.6 -- I'll check to see if there is a later version.